# How can I sort number which are of type string?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sorting

In Angular project I have Object which contains as one of the key `Quantity`. I am displaying `Quantity` as column on the table.

This column contains `numbers which are of type strings`. I cannot change the datatype as json data stores Quantity as string.

Example - `2, 54, 13, N/A, 12` as strings

How can I sort this column on the frontend?

.html

```
  <th *ngIf="searchViewSettings?.fields?.quantity" scope="col" class="link">
      <responsive-text large="Quantity"></responsive-text>
    </th>
```

Comment: You can try using a Pipe https://angular.io/guide/pipes